# Trying to print the lesser string from standard input, getting mixed outputs

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lesserString2 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
    int y = 0;
    int result = 0;
    String s = null;
    String q = null;
        while (y < 2) {
            s = r.nextLine();
            y = y + 1;
            q = r.nextLine();
            y = y + 1;
        }
        if (y >= 2){
            result = s.compareTo(q);
        }
        if(result == 0) {
            System.out.println("The strings are equal, please try again.");
        } else if(result == 1) {
            System.out.println("Lesser is: " + s);
        } else if(result < 0) {
            System.out.println("Lesser is: " + q);
        }
}
}
```

I am getting mixed results when I try to submit two different sentences through standard input.
For instance...

```
C:\Users\...>java lesserString2
how does the cat jump
very quickly i think
Lesser is: very quickly i think

C:\Users\...>java lesserString2
Jack Sprat can eat no fat
His wife can eat no lean
```

Why didn't it work the second time? How can I make it work every time? The second one I tried literally outputs nothing... It is just a blank line.

Comment: As a side node, may i ask what the while loop is used for?

Comment: @KevinEsche I only want the program to read two sentences so each time it reads a line 1 is added to y. So when y is equal to 2 then it will end the loop and compare them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there was no output for the second one, it just output a blank line.

Comment: @pabloescobrah: Ah, okay, that's issue #3.2 on the list of issues in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two main issues are that you're using `result == 1` where you need to be using `result > 0` (the positive value from `compareTo` may not be `1`; more in item #3.2 below), and that you have your comparisons backward, so you're actually showing the "greater" of the two strings rather than the lesser (item #3.1).

But that code has a variety of other issues, here's a list:

1. The `while (y < 2)` loop is completely unnecessary: `y` starts at `0` and you add `1` to it twice, so it will always execute exactly once.
2. The `if (y >= 2)` branch is completely unnecessary (see #1).
3. You're misusing the return return value of `compareTo` in two different ways:

   1. When you get a value greater than `0`, you're saying `s` is the "lesser" string. That value indicates `s` is the **greater** string.
   2. You're comparing it `== 1`, but [`compareTo`'s contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) **does not guarantee** that it will be `1`, just that it will be a positive number if `s` is greater than `q`, `0` if they're equal, or a negative number if `s` is less than `q`. The positive number may not be `1`.
4. In Java, class names are initially-capped. So `LesserString2`, not `lesserString2`.
5. It's always best to use *meaningful names* for your variables.

The reason you're not getting any output is #3.2 in the above list. You're getting a positive value, but not `1`.

Here's a version with the issues above addressed:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LesserString2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int result;
        String firstString;
        String secondString;

        firstString = inputScanner.nextLine();
        secondString = inputScanner.nextLine();
        result = firstString.compareTo(secondString);
        if (result == 0) {
            System.out.println("The strings are equal, please try again.");
        } else if (result < 0) {
            System.out.println("Lesser is: " + firstString);
        } else { // No need for: if (result > 0) {
            System.out.println("Lesser is: " + secondString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @KevinEsche: Thanks. I swapped the operators instead. You may have to hit refresh, I'd forgotten to do it, posted, and fixed it within five seconds. But...

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your condition. 
you need to change  `if(result == 1)` to `if(result >0)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documenation of the return value. It does not only return `-0, 0, 1`

> the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; a value less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument; and a value greater than 0 if this string is lexicographically greater than the string argument.

If you would print the result you would notice that the result has the value of `2`.

You need to change this `else if(result == 1)` part to `else if(result > 0)`

EDIT: also you need to swap the print of the Lesser value since you are allways writing the lexicographically higher value as the lesser value.

Answer (score 1):

in the compareTo method, the result can be either

1. Less than 0, if compareTo sees that the instance is "lesser" than the parameter.
2. Bigger than 0, if compareTo sees that the instance is "greater" than the parameter. or
3. Equals to 0, if compareTo sees that the instance is equal.

So change

```
} else if(result == 1) {
```

to

```
} else if(result > 0) {
```